# Зачем setSupportActionBar использовать?

Tags: java, android

Зачем используется

```
setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar));
```

в `onCreate`, если при добавлении его в XML

```
<include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
```

он и так появляется?

Comment: в принципе, если прочитать `setSupportActionBar` и перевести, то смысл сразу станет понятен

Comment: @iFr0z да смысл понятен, но не понятно было почему все отлично работает и без этой строчки, но спасибо `pavlofff` за нормальное обьяснение

Comment: @pavlofff Если я правильно понял, то без этой строки я не смогу установить в `ToolBar` `NavigationDrawer` и всякие остальные доп. элементы?

Comment: без этой строки он не будет использоваться при формировании меню, экшн кнопок, показа заголовков, управления кнопкой назад и тому подобного

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот метод назначает `Toolbar` выполнять функции `ActonBar`.

Тулбар сам по себе всего лишь виджет, фактически просто `Layout`, экшенбар - управляющий элемент системы, например туда выводятся меню, заголовки, кнопки управления навигацией и тп. - без привязки тулбара методом `setSupportActionBar()` всего этого вы в нем не увидите.