# Проблемы с установкой Toolbar в android приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Почему при выполнении кода в `MainActivity`:

```
toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Строчка     `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` выдает ошибку:

> setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) in
>   AppCompatActivity cannot be applied to (android.widget.Toolbar)

Хотя в разметке объекта `Toolbar` я указал:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Наследуйте класс от `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @McDaggen Если вы говорите о классе `MainActivity` то он и так отнаследован от `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Хмм, странно, вы создали новый проект и такая проблема?

Comment: Код импортов и `onCreate` в студию

Answer (score 1):

Ответ вы можете найти по этой ссылке [Зачем setSupportActionBar использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526764/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-setsupportactionbar-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Это ни как не помогает мне исправить ошибку в коде

Comment: А почему вы используете именно android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, а не просто android.widget.Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

В вашей MainActivity вы должны импортировать

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

а не

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у тебя в MainActivity импортировался Toolbar `android.widget.Toolbar`, проверь импорты.

Answer (score 0):

Все. Я разобрался. Не знаю почему, но вместо `setSuportActionBar()` я попробывал использовать `setActionBar()`. Протестил, все работает.